# Prolog: append a list to itself

Tags: prolog

suppose I have a list ListSum, and I want to append a new list to ListSum recursively, like

```
appList(ListSum):-
    %%generate a list: ListTemp,
    append(ListTemp,ListSum,ListSum),
    appList(ListSum).
```

but append(ListTemp,ListSum,ListSum) didn't work in the way i wanted.

Can anyone help me out?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand the concept of unification (or actually "matching" as implemented in Prolog). You can't bind two or more values to the same variable. Variables in Prolog once matched persisted its value until the final goal achieved, or fails somewhere. After that, if there're more possibilities then the variable is re-instantiated with another value and so on.

For example, if I query appList([]), then the append would be tested to match as:

```
append(ListTemp,[],[])
```

If ListTemp isn't empty list, this clause would fail because the semantic of append is "append the first argument with second, both are lists, resulting in the third". The recursive call to `appList(ListSum)` would be called as `appList([])` since ListSum is matched with [] previously, resulting in infinite recursion (fortunately, if ListTemp isn't [], this won't be reached).

You must have two arguments in the clause, where one is the original list, and the other is the resulting list. The first two argument of append is then ListSum and ListTemp (depends on the append order you want), while the third is the resulting list. Done, no recursion required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but i kinda need to use recursion, because I don't know how many ListTemp I will generate yet.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you said now.

Comment: i would love to, but i don't have enough repuattion

Answer (score 0):

here's a non-recursive solution, not sure why you even need recursion:

```
appself(L,X) :- append(L,L,X).
```